# Select a div from a function which is called by a button using event.target.id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="unit0">
<input onclick="getFeedback()" id="46003" class="btn" type="button" value="Upload assignment 1 here">
<input onclick="getFeedback()" id="46001" class="btn" type="button" value="Upload assignment 2 here">
</div>
```

and my getFeedback function

```
function getFeedback(){
       console.log("This function's caller was " + event.target.id);
       $.get('moodle/api.php',{action: "getfeedback", id: event.target.id},  function(data) {   
});
}
```

How would I select the div from that function? I want to append the output of the $.get to the div which contains the event.target.id

Comment: Do you actually get the event in that function in any other browser than IE, where the event is global ?

Comment: @adeneo: It's global in Chrome as well, but not Firefox.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - Yes it is, always forget that, but you're right. Still not the right way to do it.

Comment: Jamie: Are you saying you have two elements with the same ID on the page?

Comment: No, They have different IDs

Comment: @JamieH: You want to insert into a div. There's only one div in your example. Is that the div into which you want  to insert?

Comment: So they *didn't* have different IDs.

Comment: Yeah, Looked like I screwed up @CrazyTrain they WERE meant to :L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `this` to the function first like:

```
<input onclick="getFeedback(this)" id="46003" class="btn" type="button" value="Upload assignment 1 here">
<input onclick="getFeedback(this)" id="46001" class="btn" type="button" value="Upload assignment 2 here">
```

Next modify the js like:

```
function getFeedback(obj) {
    console.log("This function's caller was " + obj.id);
    $.get('moodle/api.php', {
        action: "getfeedback",
        id: obj.id
    }, function (data) {
        // Get the parent div like
        var $div = $(obj).closest('div');
    });
}
```

Comment: Uhm. For some reason it seems to be selecting my container div, not the unit div?

Comment: #unit0 can't be used :/. There are many units which have different numbers. eg unit1, unit2

Comment: I have updated the code. Try using the `div` and closing the `input` tags.

Comment: Closest seems to work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRcAM/). Don't know why it's selecting your container div.

Comment: `input` elements shouldn't have closing tags.

Comment: Had a silly bug with my html generation stuff. Causing not unique ids :P. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.parent`, like so:

```
var parent_div = $(event.target).parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without inline `onClick`

```
<div id="unit0">
 <input id="46003" class="btn" type="button" value="Upload assignment 1 here">
 <input id="46001" class="btn" type="button" value="Upload assignment 2 here">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input.btn').on('click',function(e){
    $.get('moodle/api.php',{action: "getfeedback", id: this.id},  function(data) {   
    });
});
```